# Using a proven subgoal in another subgoal in Coq

Tags: coq

Let's say I want to prove `P : A -> (B /\ C)`. After `intros. split.`, Coq generates two subgoals where I prove `B` and `C` separately, with `A` as premise. Suppose I've proved the first subgoal and entered the second. Is there some way to introduce the previously proven subgoal, so that I have `B` in the context?

One obvious way would be to refactor the original theorem into `P1 : A -> B` and `P2 : A -> C`, but it would be nice If I could skip that, especially for making compact automated proofs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could `assert B.` before `split.` and prove it, then `split` and prove `B` by using the assumption, and go ahead and prove `C` with `B` available.

Alternatively, you could build a:

```
Theorem and_intro_2 :
  forall A B C : Prop,
    (A -> B) ->
    (A -> B -> C) ->
    A -> B /\ C.
Proof. firstorder. Qed.
```

And apply it immediately at the start.